# Link to home page renders blank

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

In my rails app, I have a link to the root that renders in all browsers as

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css"></style>
  </head>
  <body>19</body>
</html>
```

Server-side I can see all assets getting passed back. For some reason the browser will not display them because if I view page source I can see ALL my markup correctly.

Now if I load or reload the page localhost:3000 normally the page and all assets are displayed correctly. If I simply refresh I get nothing.

The only time this occurs is when I click a link back to the homepage like a href="/".

The behavior does not occur if I hardcode a href="localhost:3000/" but I don't want to do this.

Rails app, Turbolinks, nowhere in code do I use the number 19, rake routes with root GET well-defined, no public/index.html. I suspect something to the degree of caching or turbolinks but I have no clue how to resolve.

Edit: Config/Routes.rb

```
SCRR::Application.routes.draw do
   root 'home#index'
   #pages
   get 'about' => 'pages#about'
   get 'history' => 'pages#history'
   get 'links' => 'pages#links'
   get 'safety' => 'pages#safety'
   get 'membership' => 'pages#membership'
   get 'events' => 'events#index'
   get 'grand_prix' => 'grand_prix#index'
   get 'newsletters' => 'newsletters#index'
end
```

Edit 2: Chrome Devtools Console Errors

This error is probably more relevant

> Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type application/x-woff: "https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/2.0/font//fontawesome-webfont.woff".
>
> jquery-2.1.0.js?body=1:1078
>
> 25115 : CS -> BG : FAILED closepopuptoplevel
>
> onloadwff.js:77

Comment: Add your config/routes.rb please!

Comment: What is the significance of `19`?

Comment: Also are you adding a href to your view code? Why not use the helper? e.g. `<%= link_to "Home Page", root_path %>`

Comment: **config/routes.rb:** http://pastebin.com/YtZzCvuJ
**Edit:** I also tried using the helper <%= link_to "Home", root_url %> and just tried yours @jkeuhlen <%= link_to "Home Page", root_path %> to no avail.

Comment: @DanielE Could you add that code to your post and not to an external link?

Comment: I'm not sure why the link_to would fail from looking at your routes. Can you use link_to in other contexts? What exactly is the error is gives you when it fails?

Comment: Other route_to calls work fine. Added console error to post. Resource in question on bootstrapcdn loads fine in all other capacities.

Comment: Would be better if you showed us the ERB code that isn't working for you

Answer (score 0):

From what you've posted, I don't know whether this would be a Rails issue or a browser issue.

I see you've tagged `turbolinks`, which could be a contributor to the issue; so let's have a look as to what the problem *might* be for you:

---

**ERB**

The ERB code you should use should be the following:

```
<%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
```

If you're trying to reference the "home" url directly, there may be an issue with how you're rendering the URL, hence why it won't show. You should ensure you use the `path helper` as described above.

This should be coupled with the correct routes:

```
#config/routes.rb
root "home#index"
resources :pages, path: "" do
  collection do
    get :about
    get :history
    get :links
    get :safety
    get :membership
    get :events
    get :grand_prix
    get :newsletters
  end
end
```

---

**Assets**

You mention the assets don't render when you refresh the page, this *could* be an issue with **Turbolinks**, although I'm not sure

Turbolinks basically just reloads the `<body>` of the page, leaving the `<head>` intact. Although this might sound like nothing to do with your issue, *perhaps* the problem is to do with the way in which Turbolinks is working with your assets

From your edit, it may appear that your assets are not loading correctly, or are at least not being shown correctly.

I hope this helps, I doubt it will give you a constructive answer

Comment: Ok as suspected I removed Turbolinks from my project and all variants in my ERB work properly now. 


Unfortunately I don't know enough about Turbolinks to get it working properly.